# CSS: adjusting spacing between letter according to container width?

Tags: html, text, css, letter-spacing

I have vertically rotated span element with some text in it:

```
span{
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.BasicImage(rotation=3);
  height: 100%;
}

.container{
  width: 40px;
  height: 500px;  /* <- this can change */
}
```

How can I make it so the spacing between the letters of the text from the span changes depending on the container's height? Basically I want the text to span over the entire height of the element...

Comment: Do you want this with CSS _only_? I think you'd have to use JavaScript...

Comment: I'm using jQuery anyway, so javascript is ok, but I don't know how :(

Comment: You may also check out this answer to adjust letter spacing to the container's width : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976289/stretch-text-to-fit-width-of-div/23168507#23168507

Answer (score 4, accepted):

...somewhere, in a javascript file far far away...

```
$(".container").each(function(idx, el) {
    $(el).css("letter-spacing", calculateSpacing(el, $(el).height()));        
});
```

You can use the [plugin found here](http://www.heychinaski.com/blog/2009/01/17/character-justification-using-jquery/), which contains the calculateSpacing function, albeit it works on width, not height (so some modification may be necessary):

http://heychinaski.com/jquery/js/jquery.charjustify.js

Answer (score 3):

I think you can't do it without javascrit, because sizes in % use width but not height.
Write a script that divide the height of the element by the number of chars inside and set it as letter-spacing.