# Stretch text to fit width of div

Tags: html, css

I have a div with a fixed width, but the text inside the div can change.

Is there a way of setting, with css or other, the spacing between the **letters** so the text always fills the div perfectly?

Comment: Do you want to change the `"spacing between the letters"` (as in [`letter-spacing`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter-spacing)) or the `font-size`? Edit: or as in @SmudgerDan's answer, the spacing between *the words*?

Comment: The spacing and font size can be adjusted to ensure the block format

Comment: why not text-align:justify ?

Comment: @GeorgeKatsanos I find "text-align:justify" doesn't always fill the area correctly. For example, if I have a div with 300px width, with the text content "Lorem Ipsum", this doesn't stretch to fill the area

Comment: @Curt, text-align:justify can work. See my answer below

Answer (score 47):

This can be done with `text-align:justify` and a small hack. See here:

```css
div{
  background-color:gold;
  text-align:justify;
}

span{
  background-color:red;
  width:100%;
  height:1em;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Lorem ipsum sit dolor
  <span> </span>
</div>
```

The trick is to add an element after the text that pretends to be really long word. The fake word is actually a `span` element with `display:inline-block` and `width:100%`.

In my example the fake word is in red and given a height of 1em, but the hack will work even without it.

Comment: This works great if we want to split the words evenly, but I wish to separate the letters evenly. Is there any way of adjusting this script to do just that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "separated the letters evenly". Do you mean that each letter should be separated uniformly, regardless of spaces?

Comment: +1 for the magic, could even be improved using an :after selector instead of the span element.

Comment: @schellmax What do you mean?

Comment: He means that this is a solution to a question that is different from the one that he asked. What he is asking is how a *single word* can be spaced to fill a container, not multiple words. Letter spacing vs word spacing. Of course, the solution should work for words as well - but by spacing every letter, not every word. If there is just a single word, your solution does nothing.

Answer (score 39):

As Mark said, `text-align:justify;` is the simplest solution. However, for short text, it won't have any effect. The following jQuery code stretches the text to the width of the container.

It calculates the space for each character and sets `letter-spacing` accordingly so the text **streches to the width of the container**.

If the text is too long to fit in the container, it lets it expand to the next lines  and sets `text-align:justify;` to the text.

**Here is a demo :**

```js
$.fn.strech_text = function(){
    var elmt          = $(this),
        cont_width    = elmt.width(),
        txt           = elmt.html(),
        one_line      = $('<span class="stretch_it">' + txt + '</span>'),
        nb_char       = elmt.text().length,
        spacing       = cont_width/nb_char,
        txt_width;
    
    elmt.html(one_line);
    txt_width = one_line.width();
    
    if (txt_width < cont_width){
        var  char_width     = txt_width/nb_char,
             ltr_spacing    = spacing - char_width + (spacing - char_width)/nb_char ; 
  
        one_line.css({'letter-spacing': ltr_spacing});
    } else {
        one_line.contents().unwrap();
        elmt.addClass('justify');
    }
};


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.stretch').each(function(){
        $(this).strech_text();
    });
});
```

```css
p { width:300px; padding: 10px 0;background:gold;}
a{text-decoration:none;}

.stretch_it{ white-space: nowrap; }
.justify{ text-align:justify; }

.one{font-size:10px;}
.two{font-size:20px;}
.three{font-size:30px;}
.four{font-size:40px;}
.arial{font-family:arial;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="stretch one">Stretch me</p>
<p class="stretch two">Stretch me</p>
<p class="stretch three">Stretch <a href="#">link</a></p>
<p class="stretch two">I am too slong, an I would look ugly if I was displayed on one line so let me expand to several lines and justify me.</p>
<p  class="stretch arial one">Stretch me</p>
<p class="stretch arial three">Stretch me</p>
<p class="stretch arial four">Stretch me</p>
<p class="arial two">Don't stretch me</p>
```

[Js fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/DPRr9/)

Comment: hello, how can I remove the the padding top and bottom on text?

Comment: This was very useful to me, I made a couple of changes so that it would work responsively too: http://jsfiddle.net/DPRr9/347/

Comment: @zeleniy nice one!

Answer (score 9):

Even easier HTML/CSS method would be to use flexbox.
It's also immediately responsive. But worth noting SEO won't pick it up if you were to use it as a h1 or something.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div>H</div>
<div>e</div>
<div>l</div>
<div>l</div>
<div>o</div>
<div>&nbsp</div>
<div>W</div>
<div>o</div>
<div>r</div>
<div>l</div>
<div>d</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/nathansonic/b6hcqrg3/1/)

Comment: top solution 2016 IMHO

Comment: a little easier with flex layout.. use on wrapper div `fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly center"`

Comment: very good idea for know in advanced text and with little `javascript` it can also work with dynamic text.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe this could help:

```
text-align:justify;
```

Comment: here is some example text for you to try: 
    <div style="font:normal 12px Arial; width:200px;">February</div>

Answer (score 6):

I found a better solution for text shorter than one line, without any extra js or tag, only one class.

```css
.stretch{ 
  /* We got 2rem to stretch */
  width: 5rem;
  /* We know we only got one line */
  height: 1rem;
  
  text-align: justify; 
}
.stretch:after{
    /* used to stretch word */
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block; 
}
```

```html
<div class="stretch">你好么</div>
<div class="stretch">你好</div>
```

Comment: @Shammoo I run the code snippet, it works as expected, have you test the snippet.

Comment: Where did you get 5rem? And why would you pick a vertical typeface?

Answer (score 5):

A little late to the party, but for a simple, pure CSS implementation consider using `flexbox`:

```css
h1.stretch {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="stretch">
  <span>F</span>
  <span>o</span>
  <span>o</span>
  <span>B</span>
  <span>a</span>
  <span>r</span>
</h1>
```

Not sure if wrapping each letter in a `span` (note any element will work) will mess with SEO, but I imagine search engines will strip tags from the `innerHTML` of tags used for important markup such as headings, etc. (Someone who knows SEO to confirm?)

Comment: this exact method was already given by Nathan answered Nov 1 '15

Answer (score 4):

Some of the above answers work well but the text has to wrap with many child **div**
and it's a lot of extra codes.
The text inside the **div** should be clean, so I made it with a help of JS.

```js
   const words = document.querySelector(".words");
words.innerHTML = words.innerText.split("").map(e => !e.trim() ? "<div>&nbsp</div>" : `<div>${e}</div>`).join("");
```

```css
.words {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="words">This is the demo text</div>
```

Comment: I like this. It can be written a bit shorter:

`.map(e => !e.trim() ? "<div>&nbsp</div>" : \`<div>${e}</div>\`);`

Answer (score 3):

**MARCH 2018**
If you are landing on this question in a more current time...

I was attempting do do what the OP asked about but with a single word and found success with the following:

**1.** Use a `<span>` and set css: `span { letter-spacing: 0px; display:block}` 
       (this makes the element only as wide as the content)

**2.** On load capture the width of the span `let width = $('span').width();`

**3.** Capture the length of the span `let length = $('span').length;`

**4.** Reset the width of the span to the container `$('span').css({'width','100%'});`

**5.** Capture the NEW width of the span (or just use the container width) `let con = $('span').width();`

**6.** Calculate and set the letter spacing to fill the container `$('span').css({'letter-spacing':(cont-width)/length})`

Obviously this can be converted to use vanilla js and it is useful even with most font styles including non mono-space fonts.

Comment: I tried to implement this [in a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rwone/69zs7v3c) and it doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're actually looking for is scaling.

Render your font with some nice-looking resolution that makes sense and then use JS to stretch it to the container by using css transforms:

```
transform: scale(1.05);
```

The benefits of this is that your text will always wit, but you run into the problem of it becoming too small to be readable.

Quick note is that you'll need to make the element you're trying to shrink/expand have absolute position:

```
position: absolute;
```

Comment: Except this messes with either the font size or the aspect ratio of the font itself which is not what is desired.

Answer (score 1):

So, still nibbling away at the edges of this problem, if you combine wener's [answer that stretches short lines of text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43728929/769780) with this [suggestion to use a real element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28269950/769780) from another thread, you can do the whole thing without needing an `:after` pseudo class.

You're substituting in an actual element and placing it **after** the one you want to justify. And this will trigger the justify alignment in the same way:

```css
header {
  background-color: #ace;
  text-align: justify;
}

.hack {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div>
    A line of text to justify
    <div class="hack"></div>
  </div>
</header>
```

This variation lets you use this trick with React and style objects:

```js
const style = {
  backgroundColor: '#ace',
  textAlign: 'justify'
};

const hack = {
  display: 'inline-block',
  width: '100%'
};

const example = (
  <header style={ style }>
    <div>
      A line of words to stretch
      <div style={ hack } />
    </div>
  </header>
);

ReactDOM.render(example, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

This is ugly and hacky enough already, but from there you'll have to pick your poison on which way you want to "fix" the excess height of the container: fixed height or negative margins for the container? relative positioning and overlapping from following elements? match the container background to the page background and pretend like that extra margin is intentional?

Comment: @VisionHive it's not supposed to. it's only solving for word justifying with css, and without pseudo-elements so that you can use css objects. see [this more current answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49479244/769780) for something like a more complete solution.

Comment: yeah, it looks like that link is the only way (no native css method). oh well.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is interested on how to justify the content and center only the last line you can use

```css
text-align: justify;
text-align-last: center;
```

see the example:

```css
.custom-justify{
   text-align: justify;
   text-align-last: center;
   padding: 0 10px 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="custom-justify">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis mollis elementum bibendum. Cras pellentesque sed augue nec lacinia. Duis at eros vel lorem cursus laoreet ac vel justo. Maecenas ornare, ligula ut porttitor sollicitudin, turpis urna auctor ipsum, a consectetur felis nibh vel est. Nullam id lorem sit amet magna mollis iaculis eu vitae mauris. Morbi tempor ut eros ut vulputate. Quisque eget odio velit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed posuere enim tellus, ut vestibulum libero dapibus ac. Nulla bibendum sapien non luctus vehicula. Aenean feugiat neque nunc, in fermentum augue posuere vel. Maecenas vitae diam in diam aliquet aliquam.<div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the [lineclamp module](https://codepen.io/tvanc/pen/BaNmVXm) I wrote you can accomplish what you want. You set a max number of lines or height you want text to take up and it finds the max font size that will fit in that number of lines, and/or trims text to make it fit.

```js
import LineClamp from "//unpkg.com/@tvanc/lineclamp/dist/esm.min.js";

const clamp = new LineClamp(document.querySelector("#elementToClamp"), {
  useSoftClamp: true,
  // Set an arbitrarily high max font size. Default min is already 1
  maxFontSize: 10000,
  maxLines: 1
});

// .apply() to apply the clamp now
// .watch() to re-apply if content changes or window resizes
clamp.apply().watch();
```

Working example: https://codepen.io/tvanc/pen/BaNmVXm

---

In the question, OP says letter spacing. In a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976289/stretch-text-to-fit-width-of-div#comment6896752_5976289), OP says letter spacing *or* font size.

Answer (score -2):

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/talker90/xddjrvrs/)

For a purely HTML/CSS solution for when you are working with even shorter text (short enough that

```
text-align: justify;
```

wouldn't work)

I followed [this great post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865194/fluid-width-with-equally-spaced-divs) as an inspiration, and placed each letter within a div

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="letters">H</div>
    <div class="letters">e</div>
    <div class="letters">l</div>
    <div class="letters">l</div>
    <div class="letters">o</div>
    <div class="letters">&nbsp</div>
    <div class="letters">W</div>
    <div class="letters">o</div>
    <div class="letters">r</div>
    <div class="letters">l</div>
    <div class="letters">d</div>
    <span class="stretch"></span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 300px; /*for example*/
    border: 1px solid gray; /*only for demonstrative purposes*/
    text-align: justify;
    -ms-text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify: distribute-all-lines;
}

.letters {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    zoom: 1
}

.stretch {
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0;
    line-height: 0
}
```