# Stretch font with CSS to fit parent’s width

Tags: javascript, css, transform

Is it possible to dynamically stretch a text width to its parent’s witdh?
In other words, I am looking to get the following result but dynamically. Solutions that require Javascript are ok.

```css
div{
  width:260px;
  border:1px solid tomato;
  background:white;
  font-size:20px;
  font-family:arial;
}
.p1{
  transform:scale(2.3,1);
  -webkit-transform:scale(2.3,1);
  -moz-transform:scale(2.3,1);
  -ms-transform:scale(2.3,1);
  -o-transform:scale(1,1.09);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.p2{
  transform:scale(5.1,1);
  -webkit-transform:scale(5.1,1);
  -moz-transform:scale(5.1,1);
  -ms-transform:scale(5.1,1);
  -o-transform:scale(5.1,1);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TEEEEXT</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <p class="p1">This is a test</p>
  <p class="p2">A test</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is a solution here using jQuery to calculate letter-spacing so text fills width of container : [Stretch text to fit width of div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976289/stretch-text-to-fit-width-of-div)

Comment: Thanks @web-tiki it doesn’t solve my issue but it is a useful resource.

Comment: Were you ever able to find a solution? I would have thought someone would have figured this out by now, but apparently it's a rare design need. I haven't found anything that quite cuts it, aside from fittext, which as you already noticed, resizes proportionately.

Comment: @chase I think the solution for now is to use SVG like that http://opensource.london/

Comment: Cool, thanks. Luckily what I'm stretching is just days/months/dates so I knew SVG was an option, but was trying to avoid it... But, whatever get's the job done! Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the jQuery plugin "FitText" (http://fittextjs.com)

Example:

```
$('#div').fitText();
```

It automatically adjusts the selector's font-size to fit the div. There are of course further options that can adjust max- and min-size for example.

Comment: But the site explicitly warns aginst use on paragrapgh text! :)

"_Oh, and don't you dare let us catch you using FitText on paragraph text. This is for gigantic display text only!_"

Comment: Thank you but I need the text *not* to be proportionally stretched as my demo shows.