# CSS Justify a single word in a table

Tags: html, css

I'm facing the following scenario:

I have table with column that there is only one word in it mac-address.
sometimes mac address can contain more letters than digits,
so it make the length of the word different.
for example : 00:1B:1B:BA:0D:AB vs 00:1B:1B:1E:0F:A8

I'm looking for solution to make the words take the same width,

already tried to use:

```
text-align: justify;
```

and

```
letter-spacing: 2px;
```

is anyone have an idea ?
attaching an image to show the described above.

[image]

Comment: I'd use a monospaced font.

Comment: This could be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976289/stretch-text-to-fit-width-of-div

Comment: helpful could be also https://github.com/davatron5000/Lettering.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution here would be to use a monospace font, probably with a CSS rule.

```
font-family:monospace;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [Monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font), that way every character will have the same width.