# Let element to fit the length of text

Tags: html, css

```css
.selectlist {
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block
  }
  .selectlist li {
    width: 60px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #EEE;
    margin: .5em;
    padding: .3em 0;
    height: 1.6em;
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
```

```html
    <ul class="selectlist">
        <li>this is line test 1</li>
        <li>this is line 2</li>
        <li>this is line 3</li>
    </ul>
```

I am trying to modify the following make `<li>` or `<ul>` element **to fit the length of given text** with CSS only. The `width: auto` makes the elements occupy the whole screen width.

```
.ul {
    margin: 0 0 2em 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    width: auto;
}
.ul li {
    width: auto;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #EEE;
    margin: .5em;
    padding: .3em 0;
    height: 1.6em;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

If it is not possible to make the list to fit the length of text then can I make the text fit into the given width of the element by modifying the above CSS?

Update:
Thanks for all the replies.
The above code formats list items to look like rectangle shape.

I tried all your suggestions and the text wraps into a second line which appear outside the rectangle shape. I just realized my question is limited to the above code scenario, not a general one.

Please see the snippet. I would like fixed length rectangle and make the text fit into it.

Comment: Do you need something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976289/stretch-text-to-fit-width-of-div ?

Comment: `display: inline-block`, `inline-table` , `inline-flex` , and `table` will shrink to fit content

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I made it into snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Do a list with in a container with rows of defined span. It will automatically start a new line rather than cutting off your text.

Comment: Please do not use answers to ask clarification questions.

Answer (score 0):

Set the .ul class to `display:inline-block`