# How to make lines the same length?

Tags: javascript

The code is a bit of a pain to paste here, because it is very repetitive.  Right now, the code in JavaScript creates 8 lines of 12 random letters each, based on a function with Math.random() that generates different letters.  When those letters appear on the page, the problem is that, obviously, the letters each have a different length.  Therefore, the lines are not all the same length and the result appears rather messy, because some lines end before/after others.
Is there a way (in JS or CSS, whichever) to make sure that the lines are all exactly the same length?

Comment: If you are looking to spread a single line to a certain width : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976289/stretch-text-to-fit-width-of-div

Answer (score 1):

you can use **text-justify** in the css for that. assuming that the generated text is in a p with a class of sampleText.

```
.sampleText{text-align:justify}
```