# Span text to the edge of the div (no white-space)

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I'm looking for a solution to span the text to the edge of the div. I don't want to have any white-space in the div.

Here is my div

```
<div class="m-card__text-front">
     <p class="fit-text">TEST TEXT</p>
     <p class="is-bold fit-text">FOO BAR</p>
     <p class="is-bold fit-text">LOREM</p>
     <p class="fit-text">LOREM IPSUM</p>
</div>
```

Now this looks looks at the moment like this

[image]

The red marked spots that is where I want the text to go span to.

I also need the **bold** text to be a different size (bigger) then the other text.

I am currently using the fitText function. https://github.com/davatron5000/FitText.js

Used like this:
`<script>     $('.fit-text').fitText(0.8); </script>`

EDIT:

Here is how the HTML looks like with the plugin:

```
<p class="fit-text" style="font-size: 38.6055px;">TEST TEXT</p>
```

Font size is being added automatically.

**EDIT 2:**

Well i just realized that i explained my problem wrong. How I explained it your function does exactly what I described. But i want to span the text and make the letter accordingly  bigger. That is why I tried to use that pluggin. Sorry Englisch is not my first language.. My bad.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stretch text to fit width of div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976289/stretch-text-to-fit-width-of-div)

Comment: Sadly no and text-align:justify; only works for longer paragraphs.

Comment: Did you review the `stretch_text` plugin that web-tiki provided? https://stackoverflow.com/a/23168507/1887854

It adjusts `letter-spacing` as a function of `redundant space` which, in my opinion, is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Will this work?

```
        <div class="m-card__text-front">
           <p style="font-size:19vw; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;">TEST TEXT</p>
           <p style="font-size:23vw; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;">FOO BAR</p>
           <p style="font-size:28vw; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;">LOREM</p>
           <p style="font-size:14.5vw; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;">LOREM IPSUM</p>
        </div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fhoj023m/1/)

You can adjust the vw(in style) if text is too small or big.
In this code, if you adjust the page size the text will adjust its font size along with the page.

Comment: If you found it as a duplicate of some other question, why not just ask for closing the question with reason of *duplicate*?

Comment: @CYr Well i just realized that i explained my problem wrong. How I explained it your function does exactly what I described. But i want to span the text and make the letter accordingly  bigger. That is why I tried to use that pluggin. Sorry Englisch is not my first language.. My bad.

Comment: @CYr I love your use of `vw` unit. It definitely does work but, the only downside is that the values need to be adjusted manually. Also, please suggest the addition of: `white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;` because currently, some text overflows to the next line.

Comment: This would only work for this exact scenario right ? If i have another module with some other text it has to be done manually (adjusted)

Comment: @MewTwo yes, the vw would have to be adjusted so that the text is not cut off.